# How to get table name from mysql result?

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

The MySQL query is as follows

```
SELECT  t1.*,  t2.*, t3.*, t4.*, t5.*, t6.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
INNER JOIN table3 t3
INNER JOIN table4 t4
INNER JOIN table5 t5
INNER JOIN table6 t6
order by t1.updated_time, t2.updated_time, t3.updated_time, t4.updated_time, t5.updated_time, t6.updated_time desc
```

from the above query i need the result with their respective table name like

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cloumn1] => data1
            [column2] => table3
            [updated_time] => data1
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cloumn1] => data1
            [column2] => table1
            [updated_time] => data2
        )
)
```

The tables have more than 15 columns which may vary.
How to achieve the result by modifying the query ?

Comment: Hi. Modify the `SELECT` part.
`SELECT t1.id as id, t1.column as colum1, t3.column3 as column3, ...`

Comment: there are more than 15 column in a table which may vary from table to table

Comment: Ok. This is not possible ... directly :) But, you can use some tricks. Ex: analyze the table structure (`SHOW COLUMNS`), and create dynamically your SQL query by adding the `t1.id as t1_id, t1.c1 as t1_c1, t2.id as t2_id, ...`. This is a tips used by some ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you make your query you can make a foreach loop to get all your column names. Something like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        echo "$key=$value";
    }
}
```

---

#### Update

If you want to get your table names in a database you can try something like this.

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM database";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
}
```

---

#### Update

First we need to get our table names. Since you don't know the table names we can get the by using this code

```
$tables = array();
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM database";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $tables[] = $row[0];
}
```

if you have the tables you can add them to the array skiping the code above

```
$tables = array("table1","table2","table3");
```

After getting all the tables we can start with the database

```
$data = array();
foreach($tables as $table){
    $query = "select * from $table";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $i=1;
        foreach($row as $key => $value){
            $data[$i][$key][$value];
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Update the code to your needs. This is a example

Comment: i want to get the table name as a another data within each result.
as you said within the foreach loop

Comment: You want to get all the data from multiple tables but the table names don't much? This is what you want to achive?

Comment: yes i need to get all data from multiple tables(columns may vary), including the respective table name as part of the data.

Comment: Ok perfect this is not a problem. Do you know what columns you need to make the select? i mean select user,pass,id,date.... from

Comment: since there are more than 15 columns and may differ from table tot table, we need to select all the columns

Comment: Ok i can give you a solution but the time that needs to execute can be tricky. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (used by some ORM)

## 1. Create a list of tables

```
<?php $tables = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3']; ?>
```

## 2. Execute SHOW COLUMNS FROM table to analyze the tables

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html

```
<?php
$structures = [];
$structuresLinear = [];
foreach( $tables as $table ) {
  $query = mysqli_query('SHOW TABLES FROM ' . $table);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
    $structures[$table][] = $row[0];
    $structuresLinear[] = sprintf('%s.%s as %s', $table, $row[0], $table . '_' . $row[0]);
  }
}
```

You will have on your `$structures` all the fields for each tables, and another one `$structuresLinear` with the different fields renamed.

Ex: `['table1.id as table1_id', 'table1.name as table1_name', ...]`

## 3. Create your final query

```
<?php
$sql  = 'SELECT ';
$sql .= implode(', ', $structuresLinear);
$sql .= ' FROM ' . implode(' INNER JOIN ', $tables);
$sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . implode(', ',
  array_map(function($t) {
    return $t . '.updated_time';
  }, $tables)
);

?>
```

## Output

You will have something like this:

```
SELECT
  table1.id as table1_id,
  table2.id as table2_id, table2.col2 as table2_col2, table2.col3 as table2_col3
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2
ORDER BY
  table1.updated_time,
  table2.updated_time
```

And the final array will be:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        table1_id = table1.id,
        table2_id = table2.id,
        table2_col2 = table2.col2,
        table2_col3 = table2.col3,
    )
)
```

You can also split each $key result to have the table or create multidim array :)